# How to apply lookup to array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lookup

How can I apply an array to a lookup dictionary in Javascript?  Example:

```
lookup = {"milk": 1, "water": 2, "soda": 3};
my_array = ["milk", "milk", "water", "milk", "soda"];

my_array.??? // This should give [1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

I've tried `my_array.map(lookup)` and I get `#<Object> is not a function`.  Same with `.filter()`, `.apply()` and the other obvious candidates.

Comment: @TrentonTrama N- no?  Not even close?  You issued a _Close As Duplicate_ vote for this?  Am I missing something or is filtering an object the same as mapping an array with an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but you have to specify a function which transforms single `my_array` element:

```js
let lookup = {"milk": 1, "water": 2, "soda": 3};
let my_array = ["milk", "milk", "water", "milk", "soda"];

let result = my_array.map(x => lookup[x]);
console.log(result);
```